# Latitude, longitude, elevation and altitude of satellites on a specific GPS receiver

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, satellite

I am currently working on calculating the GPS receiver's latitude and longitude coordinates by using three satellites above the earth. I have used the website https://www.n2yo.com/ to get information on latitude, longitude, elevation and altitude of satellites, but I don't know which three satellites should I use to determine the location of the GPS receiver.

Given that the GPS receiver is located at latitude 30 degree longitude 120 degree, may I know the name of three satellites that uses to determine the location of the GPS receiver with information of latitude, longitude, elevation, and altitude, and the time that location of the satellites measured?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Are you asking which satellites to use to fix a position or are you wanting to know which satellites gave you a fix?

Comment: To.me, this sounds like some homework or exam stuff... Could you please explain a bit more about the background if it is something else?

Comment: Time is also an unknown, so you need 4 satellites. The name of the satellites is provided by the receiver, it does not know which satellites are in the sky until it receives their signals and identifies them. At least that's how it works. Still, if you want to know which satellites are closest to the zenith, I suppose you could calculate the zenith coordinates on a sphere of approximate radius of the orbits, calculate the distances of each satellite to the zenith and choose the three closest.

Comment: GNSS satellites, including the GPS ones, are not geosynchronous, as Gabriel De Luca was explaining. A bit of info [here](https://gisresources.com/gps-field-observation-data-processing_2/)